# Erro ao instalar aplicações em relação a Python no Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ubuntu

Tô querendo colocar django, já fiz todo processo e tudo mais, porém quando vou fazer **pip install django** ou outras coisas referente a python, sempre da esse erro.

```
marcos@MarcosViana:~$ sudo apt-get -f install
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências       
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
0 pacotes atualizados, 0 pacotes novos instalados, 0 a serem removidos e 13 não atualizados.
4 pacotes não totalmente instalados ou removidos.
Depois desta operação, 0 B adicionais de espaço em disco serão usados.
Configurando python-setuptools (33.1.1-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-setuptools.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-setuptools.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote python-setuptools (--configure):
 sub-processo script post-installation instalado retornou estado de saída de erro 127
Configurando python-sqlparse (0.2.2-1) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-sqlparse.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-sqlparse.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote python-sqlparse (--configure):
 sub-processo script post-installation instalado retornou estado de saída de erro 127
Configurando python-tz (2014.10~dfsg1-0ubuntu2) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-tz.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-tz.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote python-tz (--configure):
 sub-processo script post-installation instalado retornou estado de saída de erro 127
Configurando python-django (1.8.7-1ubuntu11) ...
/var/lib/dpkg/info/python-django.postinst: 6: /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-django.postinst: pycompile: not found
dpkg: erro ao processar o pacote python-django (--configure):
 sub-processo script post-installation instalado retornou estado de saída de erro 127
Nenhum relatório apport escrito pois MaxReports já foi atingido
                                                               Erros foram encontrados durante o processamento de:
 python-setuptools
 python-sqlparse
 python-tz
 python-django
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

se puderem me ajudar ficarei grato, esse não foi comando para o django, mas é o mesmo erro. Se puderem ajudar, ficarei muito grato.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Até onde eu sei pra instalar o django é via pip e não apt-get.
Outra coisa, para instalar o django é recomendado usar uma virtualenv para evitar conflitos entre projetos se você estiver desenvolvendo-os simultaneamente.

Primeiro instala o virtualenv

```
sudo python -m pip install virtualenv
```

Se for para o python 3

```
sudo python3 -m pip install virtualenv
```

Cria uma pasta para o projeto ou se já existir, entra nela.
Dentro da pasta você vai criar um ambiente

```
python -m virtualenv "nome_do_ambiente"
```

Ou se for para o python 3

```
python3 -m virtualenv "nome_do_ambiente"
```

Agora você ativa o ambiente e instala as dependências necessárias para o projeto

```
source nome_do_ambiente/bin/activate
python -m pip install django
```

Caso ainda tenha dúvidas sobre alguma coisa em relação ao virtualenv, consulte a documentação
[Virtualenv Docs](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/)

Caso você não consiga realizar os passos acima, tenta reinstalar o python.